# Derived class: using Base class member in initializer list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang

First snippet of code:

```
struct Base
{
    int x{};
};

struct Derived :
    Base
{
    Derived()
        : y{x}
    {
    }

    int y;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

Compiles fine on:

- [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/me6GaCcMdOHrHkSn) (6.0.0)
- [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/D8LEtvCgsSOc5qMI) (3.8.0)
- [vc++](http://rextester.com/TMGJ26533) (Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, 18.00.31101)

Second snippet of code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int N>
struct Base
{
    int x = N;
};

static const int When0 = -1;

template<int N>
struct Derived :
    std::conditional<N == 0,
        Base<When0>,
        Base<N>>::type
{
    Derived()
        : y{x}
    {
    }

    int y;
};

int main()
{
    Derived<0> d;
}
```

Compiles fine on:

- [vc++](http://rextester.com/EQEXCC5426)

Will not compile on:

- [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lcvW3b1NGeYzsnTp)
- [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7LMCsTpPTCqPuT8q)

To fix gcc and clang, I need to specify `x`'s class:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int N>
struct Base
{
    int x = N;
};

static const int When0 = -1;

template<int N>
struct Derived :
    std::conditional<N == 0,
        Base<When0>,
        Base<N>>::type
{
    using base_t = typename std::conditional<N == 0,
        Base<When0>,
        Base<N>>::type;

    Derived()
        : y{base_t::x}
    {
    }

    int y;
};

int main()
{
    Derived<0> d;
}
```

See (vc will compile it too):

- [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ce4WoonqxqmRsgwQ)
- [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sktqVanF3n2JnIdQ)

Questions: Which compiler(s) is correct ? What standard says about this ?

Thanks

Comment: Disabling "language extensions" (`/Za`) in Visual Studio makes it reject your second snippet. Rule of thumb that holds way too often: when in doubt, VC++ is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard problem of accessing a base class (non-dependent) member from a templated derived class. See [this FAQ entry](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members).

Changing it to simply `this->x` also works, so VC++ is wrong here.